# Full body iframe

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

Is it a good practice to serve a page from another domain using a full body iframe? What kind of penalties (performance, CORS, etc.) would it have?

I'm negotiating a partnership with another website, and one of the conditions is to serve my content from one of its subdomains in order to count the traffic as their own for third-party audience companies, like ComScore and Google Analytics.

So, in order to keep my domain and protect my brand, I was thinking of serving from my domain a full body iframe pointing to my partner subdomain, which will be pointing to my servers. With this configuration, users will see my address in the navigation bar, but all the traffic and content will be counted as my partner's. Is this considered a good practice?

Comment: If this were good practice we would see this being done a lot. Personally I would suspect some kind of scam or malware if a site tries to hide it's URL (also I'm pretty sure a full body iframe would make it problematic to set bookmarks).

Comment: It's is made to sum audiences: it's easier to sell advertising for a bigger audience than a small one